# Posting a Facebook Story causes two entries to appear in Activity Log

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting a Facebook Story using an Open Graph Action and Object. Everything seems to work great except when I look on my activity log. I am seeing two entries, one expected one

```
"<'name> <'action> <'noun> in <'game>"
```

but I am seeing one that I don't expect

```
"<'name> posted a <'noun> in <'game>"
```

I've tracked it down and it seems to get posted as soon as I create the Open Graph object using `FB.API("/me/objects/<'game>:<'object>", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, CreateObjectCallback, oParams);`

Which I believe is required to create the object that will be used in the story post. Does anyone know how to create this object for use in the story post without having an entry added to the activity log for it?

Thanks!

Comment: you can go to the appdashboard and click get code to view sample code for each SDK.

Comment: Solved this? I'm having the same issue!